# Linux/CMD environment and terminal on website

Tags: command-line, web

I am looking for a way to incorporate a command line interface into my website. Specifically I have 2 servers, one running Linux distro and the other Windows. People can request accounts and if I approve them they get a user partition on either of the servers.

They can then sign in on the website and access the servers through a command line interface. I saw a couple of repos that do something similar for the Amazon EC2 servers but was wondering if there is anything more general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [shellinabox](https://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/). This runs a daemon on the server and can be accessed through a specified port. You simply have to enter the IP of your server and the port number and you can log in over a browser.